# In general should problems you might have with a question's answer belong in the comment section or in a new answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, wrong-answers

In general should problems you might have with a post's answer belong in the comment section or in a new answer.

Specific example a question's answer comes to the correct conclusion, but is filled with inaccuracies or irrelevant information.

> Q: is 7 an even number?
>
> A: No, i doubt it. 7 is a single digit number, and since most single
> digit numbers are odd, there is more of a chance it is odd. Also 7 is
> a prime number and most prime numbers are odd. Not to mention my mom loves even
> numbers and she doesn't love the number 7.

Here we see the correct answer based on either misleading or correct but irrelevant information.

This is a simple question as we know most questions are much more complicated.  So is it expected that one chimes in with a new answer, or is it OK to point out the problems with the given answer in its comments?

My problem with a new answer is not always might one have the information to come to a conclusion, but rather does have enough information to rebuke a posted answers information.
And pointing it out in the comment may help someone to reconsider what they just read.

And if this isn't a particularly popular topic that may only get the one single answer and thus accepted and up-voted, would not this be valuable in the comment rather than being left out entirely?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see the current answer get improved, leave a comment asking for improvements, such as:

> You're right that 7 isn't even, but it's not because of what you said.  Even numbers are evenly divisible by 2, which isn't true for 7.  Also, anecdotal answers don't work well on SE because we don't know your mom or how rigorous she is.  Are you willing to [edit] this answer to focus on the better explanation?

Note: avoid getting into a discussion or argument in comments; that's not what they're for.  You want to point out the flaw, suggest a correction (since you know it, in this case), ask for an edit, and fend off a long discussion.

(You might notice that even though the prime-number thing is *correlated* with "not even" (with one exception), I didn't bring it up.  You don't need to do a point-by-point critique; focus on the subset that, if addressed, fixes the problem.)

If you know that the reasoning is wrong but you don't know what the correct reasoning is, you'd instead say something like:

> You're right that 7 isn't even, but I don't think that's the right reasoning.  Also, it's better to give a mathematical rule, not a probability-based argument or one based on the opinions of someone we don't know and can't consult.  Can you [edit] in a better way of determining the answer?

If all that sounds like too much work (or too much altruism), you can instead just post your own answer giving the correct reasoning.  If the community agrees they'll vote it up.  Optionally, you can leave a comment to the effect of "right conclusion, but I disagree with the reasoning; see my answer (link)".

Comment: @ Monica Do you ever feel is appropriate to state your opinion on the quality of the answer or always let readers come to their own conclusion. consider that you might be an expert on the subject while other readers may be entirely uninformed. Might it ever help stress your point?

Comment: @axa opinions lead to arguments in my experience; presenting facts (especially with links or citations) and letting the readers draw their own conclusions works better.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to point out flaws with an answer, leave a comment.

If you want to post a better answer, write an answer. (I suggest that an answer with the same end result but a more comprehensive/correct explanation is a better answer.)

Comment: @ale So your opinion is that the correct procedure should be based on what the person wants to do?

Comment: @ Pierre, Ive been in the same situation you are in now, so i can instruct you preciously on what you need to do, you need to open an account with Meta, check, and then post your question there asking how to follow up here... though seriously, ive gotten so chewed out on what i believe were hurt feelings when pointing out flaws, i need to learn the proper procedure, or find a baseline to reference when it happens again

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how much your meaning approaches to the nature of existing answer.

There can be three possible solutions: 1.Comment, 2.Edit, 3.Answer.

Let me quote notable and related points from Help Center:

When to comment:

> Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;

When not to:

> Suggesting corrections that don't fundamentally change the meaning of the post; instead, make or suggest an edit;
>
> Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one);

So, If you want to suggest minor corrections or add information that clarify or improve the answer, you should add comment.

But if your intention deviates considerably than you should add your answer instead.

In this case, I think you might be agree with only bold part:

> A: **No**, i doubt it. 7 is a single digit number, and since most single digit numbers are odd, there is more of a chance it is odd. Also **7 is a prime number and** most **prime numbers are odd.** Not to mention my mom loves even numbers and she doesn't love the number 7.

And your reasoning (I suppose) "not multiple of two" or "not divisible by two" would be considerably different than that of existing answer. So, In such case, I think adding your answer is more appropriate.

Again as I said, it depends what is your approach comparatively to existing answer and possibility of accepting your suggested changes by answerer.